# Query javascript value in php DOMDocument

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

How to get js value in php dom.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$html ='<html>
<body>Hello <b id="test">Hello World</b>.</body>
<script>
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Blah Blah";
var test = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
</script>
</html>';

$dom->validateOnParse = true; 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$belement = $dom->getElementById("test");
echo $belement->nodeValue;
```

Output : Hello World

i want to output: Blah Blah

Comment: You have a quote issue - both your php string and your javascript quotes are using single quotes `'`. Either change one of them to double quotes, or escape the single quotes in your javascript code

Comment: You can't. The code in your HTML string is not executed so the value of the `b` element is not changed.

Comment: DOMDocument is a DOM parser, it doesn’t execute any scripting. If you want to get the result of something like this how it would show in an actual browser after the JavaScript was executed, then you are looking for what is called a _headless browser_.

Comment: Thanks all, i solved my problem with phantomjs :D

Comment: If you solved your problem with phantomjs, why did you accept an answer that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this below code

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
?>
<html>
<body>Hello <p id="test">Hello World</p>.</body>
</html>
<script>
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Blah Blah";
var test = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
</script>
<?php
$dom->validateOnParse = true; 
$dom->loadHTML();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$belement = $dom->getElementById("test");
echo $belement->nodeValue;
?>
```